# How to load .html files in the Home page with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, routes, single-page-application

I have created single page application. I used ColdFusion 2016, JQuery, JavaScript, HTML5 and Bootstrap 3. I tried to keep it simple and so far everything is running just fine. One thing that I would like to change is the way `.html` files are loaded in my application. Here is the current code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Example Application</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="animated_favicon1.gif">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Home.css">
        <cfif SysAdmin EQ 1><link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/Admin.css"></cfif>

        <!---*** Start: JQuery 3.3.1 version. ***--->
        <script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!---*** End: JQuery 3.3.1 version. ***--->

        <!---*** Start: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.7/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
        <!---*** End: Bootstrap 3.3.7 version files. ***--->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-container" class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <p class="navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> <b>Welcome to Example Application!</b></p>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul id="main-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="active"><a href="/user-page" data-container="user-container">User</a></li>
                                <cfif SysAdmin EQ 1><li><a href="/admin-page" data-container="admin-container">Administrator</a></li></cfif>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                        
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>JohnM</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="confirmation" data-popout="true" role="button" id="log_out">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div id="user-container"><cfinclude template="User.html"></div>
            <cfif SysAdmin EQ 1><div id="admin-container"><cfinclude template="Admin.html"></div></cfif>  
        </div>
        <cfinclude template="Modal.html">
        <script language="javascript" src="JS/Home.js"></script>
        <cfif SysAdmin EQ 1><script language="javascript" src="Admin.js"></script></cfif>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then here is the function that controls which container will be displayed on the screen first and the way user can switch and show different container:

```
$("#main-menu li a").on('click', mainMenu);
function mainMenu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemID = $(e.target).attr('data-container');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $('#main-container > div[id="' + itemID + '"]').show();
    $('#main-container > div:not([id="' + itemID + '"])').hide();
}
```

On page load this code is triggered:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Trigger on click function on the main menu element.
    $('#main-menu').find('a[data-container="user-container"]').trigger('click');
});
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to load `.html` containers in JQuery? I read one article where they showed small framework `Sammy.js`. I'm not sure if that is necessary for me to use or there is other ways to achieve this. If anyone can provide some example that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: I think what you're looking for us http://api.jquery.com/load/ which takes a html returned by a call and puts it inside a DIV of your choice

Comment: @Budyn Is there a way to check if that user is administrator first and then return result and load `.html`? You can see that I use coldfusion to check if user has set admin flag to 1 or 0. Based on that admin container will be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(_ => {
  const $content = $('#content');
  $.get('content.html')
  .done(data => $content.html(data))
  .fail(($xhr, errorMsg) => $content.text(`Error: ${errorMsg}`));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use .load in Jquery and assign it on a container

```js
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_home").on("click", function() {
        $("#content").load("content.html");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I always just embed it straight in the HTML so I can see whats happening and to ensure a logical flow.

```
<script>$("#mydiv").load("something.html");</script>
```